# Navigating to a link that is not part of the Django application is throwing a 404 error

Tags: django, .htaccess, url-routing, whmcs

I was running a wordpress site at "mydomain.com" with a whmcs installation at mydomain.com/portal. everything was fine. I recently got rid of the wordpress installation and set up a Django website at mydomain.com. The WHMCS installation at mydomain.com/portal is still there.

But here is the issue:

- visiting mydomain.com/portal is giving me 404 error
- same thing for mydomain.com/portal/admin (404 error)

the pages load if i visit mydomain.com/portal/index.php or mydomain.com/portal/login

My current .htaccess file in mydomain.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"


# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/mydomain.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/usr/virtualenv/mydomain.com/3.9/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END

# Newly added text below here, in order to troubleshoot CSS not showing up
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /home/usr/mydomain.com/staticfiles/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /home/usr/mydomain.com/blog_images/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>


<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
    FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
```

I tried adding the below but it did not help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal/
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
```

I am trying to get the whmcs installation to load like it used to at mydomain.com/portal instead of having to link to index.php

Comment: _"I tried adding the below but it did not help."_ - all you are doing there, is disabling the HTTP to HTTPS redirect, if the requested path starts with `/portal/`. What you actually need to do, is prevent any requests below that path prefix, from being send through the django routing to begin with. (Only, I can't tell how exactly the last part is even implemented here.)

Comment: How would I implement it? im totally lost at this point :(

Comment: Is page loading when you go to "mydomain.com/portal/" ?

Comment: no. Its giving me my 404 page. but if I go to mydomain.com/portal/index.php, then the page loads fine. Also going to mydomain.com/portal/login loads the page fine.

mydomain.com/portal/admin throws 404 again
but mydomain.com/portal/admin/login loads the page fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have transitioned from a WordPress site to a Django site, the .htaccess rules might need some adjustments to accommodate the new setup.
Here's a revised version of your .htaccess file that should direct requests to the WHMCS installation properly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Redirect requests to WHMCS installation
RewriteRule ^portal(.*)?$ /portal/index.php [L]

# Your existing rules below
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"

# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION BEGIN
PassengerAppRoot "/home/user/mydomain.com"
PassengerBaseURI "/"
PassengerPython "/home/usr/virtualenv/mydomain.com/3.9/bin/python"
# DO NOT REMOVE. CLOUDLINUX PASSENGER CONFIGURATION END
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION BEGIN
<IfModule Litespeed>
</IfModule>
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY. CLOUDLINUX ENV VARS CONFIGURATION END

# Newly added text below here, in order to troubleshoot CSS not showing up
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ /home/usr/mydomain.com/staticfiles/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ /home/usr/mydomain.com/blog_images/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:ico|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
    FileETag MTime Size
</FilesMatch>
```

"RewriteRule ^portal(.*)?$ /portal/index.php [L]" should redirect any requests to **/portal** to **/portal/index.php**, allowing WHMCS to handle the routing internally as it did before.

Comment: I updated my .htaccess to add 
# Redirect requests to WHMCS installation
RewriteRule ^portal(/.*)?$ /portal/index.php [L]

It did not fix the issue. Still getting the same 404. Also tried on geotargetly.com to make sure it wasnt a cache issue. 

Any clue what else it might be? could it be something to do with the .htaccess inside the /portal folder?

Comment: .htaccess file that my added rule should be at the root folder. You should seperate htaccess rules, one for root, one for portal folder and the others. Especially my rule should be at the root folder htaccess file.

Comment: yup its on the root folder at /home/usr/mydomain.com/

What I meant was, there is another .htaccess file in the /portal folder. thats the .htaccess from whmcs installation (autogenerated i guess)

Comment: Replace my rule with RewriteRule ^portal(.*)?$ /portal/index.php [L]

Comment: What happens, when you try just `RewriteRule ^portal/ - [L]` instead? (To just let all those request pass thru unchanged, and then let the rewriting that WHMCS itself has set up in that folder, take over.)

Comment: tried both "RewriteRule ^portal(.*)?$ /portal/index.php [L]" and "RewriteRule ^portal/ - [L]". Neither made any difference. Made sure to hard refresh and also checked on geopeeker just to make sure. :(

Comment: As I said earlier on, I can't tell which part of this makes the django routing work to begin with - my suspicion is that the "Passenger" stuff is what achieves that? `PassengerBaseURI "/"` - according to documentation, this is _"Used to specify that the given URI is an distinct application that should be served by Passenger."_ - so I am guessing, this makes _all_ the requests get passed to passenger, and therefor eventually django - and that internal URL rewriting can't do anything about that to begin with.

Comment: that is correct, the passenger is what points to the application. PassengerBaseURI "/" is basically pointing to my root which is /home/usr/mydomain.com or mydomain.com

Comment: Then the internal rewrite to `/portal/index.php` might as well have worked - but this "modified" request then gets still passed on to passenger, because that path of course is still below the base URL of just `/`. Maybe(!) you can move all the passenger stuff into an `<if>` condition, that checks the requested URI did _not_ start with `/portal/`? `<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ ^portal/">` or something like that. (Not sure if the request URI in this context starts with a leading slash or not, so you might have to experiment a little.) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html